# Trigger multiple emails from breezing forms

Tags: joomla, breezingforms

Im using breezing forms1.7.5 on Jomla 3

I want to trigger two different emails to two different email ids on form submit

Need Help

Comment: There is a field called "Mail recipient" in form Propertions, you just can put there multiple  mails, example:
`ex1@example.com ; ex2@example.com ; ex3@example.com`

Comment: @AndrewSpartan Please add your comment as answer....it seems to be correct

Answer (score 1):

There is a field called "Mail recipient" in form Propertions, you just can put there multiple mails, example:

```
ex1@example.com ; ex2@example.com ; ex3@example.com
```

Yes, you need to separate, them with spaces before AND after semicolons.